# Property for subclass UICollectionViewCell

Tags: swift, class, scoping

Here is my class

```
class myCell: UICollectionViewCell {

     public var myProp:String = ""

     let myControl:UILabel = {

           let label = UILabel()
           label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
           label.Text = myProp

        return label
    }()

}
```

I want to use the `myProp` within the creation of my UI elements but the compiler is saying I cannot use `myProp`.

or why is this incorrect

```
class myCell: UICollectionViewCell {

     public var myLabel:UILabel = UILabel()

     let myControl:UIView = {
            let ui = UIView()

            myLabel = {   

              let lbl = UILabel()                                   

              lbl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

              return lbl
            }()

               ui.AddSubView(myLabel)

            return ui
        }()

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
     public var myProp:String = ""

     override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

    }

     func setText() {
        let myControl:UILabel = {
            let label = UILabel()
            label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            label.text = myProp

            return label
        }()
        self.addSubview(myControl)
    }
}
```

During rendering, in `cellForRowAtIndex` need to implement this for adding subview with text.

```
 override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
    cell.myProp = "text"
    cell.setText()

    return cell
}
```

Comment: but this hides myControl.  When I use the cell during the rendering of the cell in the collection view, I would do something like cell.myProp = "text"..  I was able to work around this.

Comment: If you want to add `UILabel` as a subview in cell init method then value not set. Because init will execute when cell initialized in `cellForRowAtIndex`. You need another method to show the text. I will update my answer very soon.

Comment: I setup my UI during cell init. all the ui elements are created and in place during init. All I do is set the text value during cellForItemAt..

Comment: the label is inside  UIView. I want to expose it at the cell level so that I can set the text at a later time.  I am able to get it to work but don't understand why I can not have a member of the class used inside the creation of another UI component